# Как изменить последнюю запись с определённым неуникальным значением?

Tags: sql, база-данных

**Элементы таблицы**

[image: Элементы таблицы]

Нужно указать время завершения заказа (может вообще не завершится) с помощью функции *now()*. Проблема в том, что *phone* не уникальный, то есть получается, что надо изменить последний заказ с этим номером. Атрибут *start* не допускает *null*.

**Пример заполнения**

[image: Пример заполнения]

Comment: `where phone=X and start=(select max(start) from tab where phone='X')`

Comment: Хотя если с NULL запись одна можно рискнуть просто `phone=X and finish is  null`